# OS X 10.10 Yosemite : How to turn OFF vibrancy (transparency) for an entire application?

Tags: transparency, osx-yosemite

This mode creates problems on some rendering and slowness.

I know this transparency mode can be turned off in MacOS preferences. But I just want to turn it off for my application.

I tried NSAppearance, but I didn't find the solution.

My current working solution is to turn it OFF for all applications:

```
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/defaults" arguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"write", @"com.apple.universalaccess", @"reduceTransparency", @"-boolean", @"true", nil]];
```